# How do I close() .executeUpdate?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am wondering, how do I close an executeUpdate statement in JAVA(JDBC)?

For example:

```
String sql = "UPDATE. .. . ..  Whatever...";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
rs.close();
```

But I couldn't do this to update. So I googled and found out that I need to use executeUpdate but how do I close the statement after?

```
String sql = "UPDATE. .. . ..  Whatever...";
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
rs.close(); ??? <------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't close the `executeUpdate`, you close the `Statement`:

```
rs.close();   // Closes the ResultSet
stmt.close(); // Closes the Statement
```

Usually best to do that with a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

```
String sql = "UPDATE. .. . ..  Whatever...";
try (
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
) {
    // Process results
}
```

try-with-resources will close both the `Statement` and the `ResultSet` for you. It was added in Java 7 (in 2011).

---

Side note: You've shown that you're using `Statement` and calling `executeUpdate(String)`. That's fine as long as there's no externally-sourced information in the SQL (nothing you've received from user input or another system, etc.). In the more common case, though, you'd want to use a `PreparedStatement`, call `setXyz` to set parameters, and then call `executeUpdate()` (the zero-args version). This habit keeps you safe from SQL injection. More explanation and examples on this useful site: http://bobby-tables.com/.

Comment: That is the OP is using JDK 7 and higher (which supports `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Yes, I'll mention that. I should hope people are using JDK 7 or higher, as it's been out for several years now.

Comment: Ok thanks. So everytime I do a stmt.executeQuery or Update do I have to close the stmt after that? Because I kept reusing the stmt until the end and then I conn.close().

Comment: @Nicky: No, you close the `Statement` when you're done with the `Statement`. Just note that you can only have one `ResultSet` open on a `Statement` instance any any given moment, so be sure you're done with the first one before you reuse the `Statement` to get another one (or don't reuse the `Statement` object, I don't think there's any real advantage to reusing it).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times when you are updating a table you don't get a `ResultSet` as the result, So no need to close the `ResultSet`.

Just close the `Statement`.